# How can I show in UI the limit of character and how much was digited for the user? Android Java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-textwatcher, charactercount

How can I do that?
I mean showing the limit of character and how much was digited on the input text.

[image: EditText Character UI]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use `TextInputLayout` widget for this task in your xml,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="50">

       <EditText
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:maxLength="50" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Here `counterEnabled` is to enable counter, and `counterMaxLength` sets the maximum range of counter.

While `maxLength` in `EditText` sets the maximum number of characters, can be enters in your EditText.

Answer (score 3):

You can [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) which is support character counting functionality. Here, I have mentioned full description on how to implement [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) with [TextInputEditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.html)

**Character Counter**

> Character Counter is a feature used by quite a few applications.
>   (Remember Twitter character limit?). Set **app:counterEnabled** to **true**
>   and **app:counterMaxLength** with the maximum number of characters you
>   want in the TextInputLayout. Character Counter is by default displayed
>   below the EditText (bottom-right) and while writing this tutorial,
>   there’s no way to change the position, yet. Styling the counter is
>   similar to styling the hint text. **app:counterTextAppearance** is the
>   attribute used this time. We’ve added the following style inside the
>   styles.xml file in our project.

```
<style name="CounterText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Counter">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_pink</item>
    </style>
```

The below xml code is from the **activity_main.xml** layout and has EditText fields with a default character counter and a custom one.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="5"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintText">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Character Counter Limit 10" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

*The output of the above code is given below.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with TextInputLayout:

```
app:counterEnabled="true"
app:counterMaxLength="250"
```

**Example**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:counterEnabled="true"
app:counterMaxLength="250">

   <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="250" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementing it would look like this:

```
private TextView mTextView;
private EditText mEditText;
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           //This sets a textview to the current length
           mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
};
```

Then you have to set the edit text to the listener:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```

Then in the layout wrap your edit text in the following TextInputLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="20"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Text Hint"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Good luck :)